# Moving an array to the end of an array

Tags: php

So I'm trying to combine $gender and $grade and then remove them from the middle of my array and put them at the end. This is what I have so far but it adds both to the end but they're still in the middle of the output file. I feel like I'm missing something simple here. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

$inputFile = "Student_Data.csv";
$outputFile = "test.csv";

$count = 0; 

$out = fopen($outputFile, "w");
$in = fopen($inputFile, "r");

while ($row = fgetcsv($in)) {
    $gender = array($row[6]);
    $grade = array($row[7]);
    $merge = array_merge ($gender, $grade);
    $final = array_merge ($row, $merge);
    $sisline = implode(",", $final) . "\r\n";

    print_r ($sisline);
    $count++;
}

fclose($out);
fclose($in);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you extract the value, remove them from the soruce.

```
$gender = array($row[6]);
$grade = array($row[7]);
unset($row[6],$row[7]);
```

or to get fancy as  single line solution.

```
$row = array_diff_key($row,array_flip(array(6,7))) + $row;
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you. I tried using unset as well but I got too complicated with it haha.

Answer (score 0):

Because the two keys you want are consecutive, you can select them and remove them in one step with `array_splice`

```
$genderAndGrade = array_splice($row, 6, 2);
$final = array_merge($row, $genderAndGrade);
```